# Issue With App Engine and Spring Boot : Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token,

Tags: java, kotlin, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm developping an App Engine application, that is basically an API. So it's a backend application I started this project approximately one year ago, and I had no issue deploying it on App Engine.

But since yesterday, each time I want to deploy a new version (with little to no change between the last working version uploaded 2 months ago) I always got the same error on my logs:

```
{
  "textPayload": "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GceMetadataQuery.readResponse(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GceMetadataQuery.queryMetadataAttribute(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GceMetadataQuery.lazyQueryAccessToken(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GceMetadataQuery.getAccessToken(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.openConnection(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.registerDebuggee(Unknown Source)",
  "insertId": "62b07762000723c9146921dc",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "version_id": "20220620t152333",
      "module_id": "default",
      "zone": "europe-west2-3",
      "project_id": "family-gift-174ff"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-06-20T13:34:26.467913Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c2cc69d1d383473699b064aeebb51ac76765d2c519588a83959e70d06404d5c7072810a3875ad50b8b30b42120cb49fc83ed242292e"
  },
  "logName": "projects/family-gift-174ff/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fcdbg_java_agent.localhost.www-data.log.INFO.20220620-133415.10",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-06-20T13:34:26.635895729Z"
}
```

Obviously, this error leads to other errors like

```
{
  "textPayload": "java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://clouddebugger.googleapis.com/v2/controller/debuggees/register\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1924)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1520)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)\n\tat com.google.devtools.cdbg.debuglets.java.GcpHubClient.registerDebuggee(Unknown Source)",
  "insertId": "62b0776200072f646724c018",
  "resource": {
    "type": "gae_app",
    "labels": {
      "zone": "europe-west2-3",
      "version_id": "20220620t152333",
      "module_id": "default",
      "project_id": "family-gift-174ff"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-06-20T13:34:26.470884Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "clone_id": "00c61b117c2cc69d1d383473699b064aeebb51ac76765d2c519588a83959e70d06404d5c7072810a3875ad50b8b30b42120cb49fc83ed242292e"
  },
  "logName": "projects/family-gift-174ff/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fcdbg_java_agent.localhost.www-data.log.INFO.20220620-133415.10",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-06-20T13:34:26.635895729Z"
}
```

or

```
{
  "textPayload": "java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.\n\tat com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar!/:8.0.25]\n\tat
And a lot more actually
}
```

I tried to do a lot of things with my service accounts, but nothing works yet, and I seriously don't know what to do.
I saw some documentations for OAuth identifications for Web App, but as there is no frontend involved, I don't really know how to implement this.
And I use this API to use with an Android and iOS application, with a MySQL database and I already implemented a jwt token based authentication so I'm really confused and I don't know what to do...

Comment: Did you make any recent changes to your organization or project policies?